# Qt on Android crashes with "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: android, qt

From some devices we keep getting crash reports, with the following stack frame:

```
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  at java.lang.Runtime.load0 (Runtime.java:929)
  at java.lang.System.load (System.java:1625)
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$4.run (QtNative.java:505)
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$2.run (QtThread.java:87)
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run (QtThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

Unfortunately, as you may see, the stack frame nowhere mentions the missing dependency.

The crash occurs during app's initialization, not even the window gets rendered.

Qt 5.15.2

Ideas?